# The state in COM object between calls is not consistent

Tags: c#, .net, com

I have a .NET COM object, that i uses to call from C code.

```
[EventTrackingEnabled(true)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class ComObject : IComObject
{
    private static XslCompiledTransform transformer = null;
    private static string transformerXsltPath = null;
    private static string TransformerXsltPath 
    {
        get
        {
            return transformerXsltPath;
        }
        set
        {
            transformerXsltPath = value;
        }
    }
    private static XslCompiledTransform Transformer
    {
        get
        {
            return transformer;
        }
        set
        {                
            transformer = value;                
        }
    }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    public bool TransformXML(String inputPath, String xsltPath, String outputPath)
    {       
        // ....
        if (Transformer == null || xsltPath != TransformerXsltPath)
        {
            Transformer = new XslCompiledTransform(true);
            Transformer.Load(xsltPath, new XsltSettings(true, true), new XmlUrlResolver());
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to keep the state of the com object, as long as i call this method. by static members. so when i'll call it again, the state members will be initialized.

But the problem is, that just the `Transformer` object stay initialized in the second call but the `transformerXsltPath` string restarted to null.

how it is possible ?

Comment: Do you remember if you had to do anything special when adding [EventTrackingEnabled(true)]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a field doesn't need to be static in order to retain its value between method calls (only variables declared inside methods have that property). Static means that the field belongs to the class, not to any instance of the class, and there is only one instance of the field, which is shared by all instances of the class (and can even be accessed without creating an instance of the class, as in `Class.field`). For more information see [fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and [static fields](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Second, I don't see how you expect the transformerXsltPath field to be modified when you don't modify it anywhere (and it's private, which means that it can't be modified outside the class).

Comment: Thanks! You're absolutely right, the problem was that I forgot to set this variable. Maybe I'm too tired :) .  In addition, I used static variables because I create several instances of this class. Thanks, again.